# Conditional query from html controls

Tags: jquery, html, django

I want to build a web page where user can select data from different html controls and form a conditional query. For instance

```
a == 2 
and 
b == 4 
and 
c == 6 
or 
x == 0
```

The data for a, b, c and x  comes from html controls and user is also able to delete different conditions in the query.

Later I want to transform this query into json/xml and send it to the server.

Appreciate your suggestions for ui framework or live examples?

PS: I am using django framework and planning to use jquery.

Answer (score 1):

You can write some easy jQuery to build a form and then you can use something like serializeArray to send it to the server:

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serializeArray

Something like the following should work pretty well for you to build off:

```
<form class="search-form" action="search.php" method="get">
  <div class="search-conditions"></div>
  <div>
    <input class="add-button" type="button" value="Add condition" />
    <input class="submit-button" type="submit" value="Search" />
  </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.add-button').click(function() {
    var selectField = $('<select name="field-boolean[]"><option value="and">AND</option><option value="or">OR</option></select>');
    $('<div class="condition"></div>')
      .append(selectField)
      .append('<input name="field-name[]" type="text" />')
      .append(' = ')
      .append('<input name="field-value[]" type="text" />')
      .appendTo('.search-conditions');
  });

  $('form').submit(function() {
    console.log($('.search-form').serializeArray('.search-form'));
    return false;
  });
});
//]]>
</script>
```